# Is it possible to lay text on rounded corners of elements?

Tags: html, css, curve, rounded-corners, text-alignment

For instance, given a simple snippet like this

```css
.outer {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
ciao
</div>
</div>
```

would it be possible to lay the text `ciao` along one of the four rounded corners of the outer `div`?

Or, more generally, is it possible to make some long text follow the whole border of the outer `div`? For instance, a long enough text could start from one side, proceed straight along that side, then curve along one of the corners, and finally proceed along the following side.

Ultimately, I'm interested in putting anything along corners, including `<ul>`s, for instance, so probably SVG is not the way to go (or is it?).

Comment: You mean, curve the text?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Is SVG allowed? Someone might supply an answer with that. [See this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/). Or [this](https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/) (pure js I think).